# Error in library(arulesViz) : there is no package called ‘arulesViz’

Tags: r

i'm using ubuntu there was an error in the version with my R and then i changed the version from 3.6.3 to 4.2 now this is not getting resolved.

i tried manually and by istall.package() also but still not working

Comment: What error do you get when you run `install.packages("arulesViz")`?

Comment: Try `install.packages("arulesViz")` - you missed out an 'n' in install